# jQuery - Retrieve values from HTML elements and return their sum

Tags: jquery, arrays, sum

I got a `form` with several `checkbox`'s where the user can choose multiple values, like so:

```
<div>
    <input id="myinput1" type="checkbox" value="choice_id_1" />
    <label for="myinput1">5</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="myinput2" type="checkbox" value="choice_id_2" />
    <label for="myinput2">10</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="myinput3" type="checkbox" value="choice_id_3" />
    <label for="myinput3">10</label>
</div>
```

I need to get the values from each `:selected` checkbox `label` and return their total sum *(ie: total = 25)*.

So far I have been trying to get the `strings` from the `labels` with the `.text()` method, make an `array` with the results, converting them to `int` with `parseFloat()` and sum the array elements... obviosly with no success.

This is what i got *(for sure not the best approach so I'm open to diferent solutions)*:

```
function totalSum() {
    var prices = $("input:checkbox:checked").siblings("label").text();
    var myArray = $.makeArray(prices);

    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        var thisVal = parseFloat(myArray[i]);
        if(!isNaN(thisVal)){
            total += thisVal;
        }
    };

    $(".mydiv").text(total);
};

totalSum();
$("input:checkbox").change(totalSum);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one thing change the `value` part of each checkbox to the same as the value of the label (if you can't do that, you can utilize the name attr of the input as shown below):

```
<div>
    <input id="myinput2" type="checkbox" value="choice_2" name="10"/>
    <label for="myinput2">10</label>
</div>
```

and then the JS can be like this:

```
function totalSum() {
    var prices = $("input:checkbox:checked");

    var total = 0;

    $.each(prices, function(index, obj){
        total += parseFloat($(obj).attr('name'));
    })


    $(".mydiv").text(total);
};
```

Comment: Sorry, thought better not to complicate the question with additional code. Thing is I can't use the value from the checkboxes to do this as I'm already using it to send the results to the database.The value is how I'm identifying the user choosen options. (edited my question)

Comment: Ok. Since i couldn't use the name attr either (sorry for the over simplification) i created a new input [type=hidden] and and duplicated my wanted values (wich i get from php) to this input value attr. Now your first suggestion worked perfectly! Thx =)

Answer (score 1):

the solution is as follow, you can go [here](http://gadgets-code.com/jquery-how-to-retrieve-values-from-html-elements-and-return-their-sum) to try out the demo

```
<form id="sum" action="#">
<div><input id="myinput1" type="checkbox" value="choice_id_1" />
<label for="myinput1">5</label></div>
<div><input id="myinput2" type="checkbox" value="choice_id_2" />
<label for="myinput2">10</label></div>
<div><input id="myinput3" type="checkbox" value="choice_id_3" />
<label for="myinput3">10</label></div>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<div id="result"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.submit').click(function(event){
     var sum = 0;
     jQuery('form#sum').find(':checkbox').each(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
       var labelVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).next().text());
       sum +=labelVal;
      }
     });
     jQuery('#result').text('The total is ' + sum);
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: That solves it perfectly too. I already got my problem solved with the var prices = $("input:checkbox:checked").siblings("label") and then using the rest of @Neal's answer, so no additional markup needed. I'll have to keep @Neal's answer approved as he was the 1st to answer and really solved my problem. Thx for the very enlightening example thought =)